# Import functions/subroutine into subclass

Tags: perl, moops

I'm using [`Moops`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moops) and I'd like something like this to work:

```perl
use Moops;

class A {
  fun f {
    print "yay,f!\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  fun g {
    f();
  }
}
B->g(); # should print 'yay, f!'
```

Instead this yields:

```
Undefined subroutine &B::f called at static-functions-lexical-scope.pl line 11.
```

I can "fix" this by inheriting from [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) in `A` and a [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) statement in `B` like so:

```perl
class A extends Exporter {
  our @EXPORT = qw(f);
  fun f {
    print "yay,f!\n";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  use A;
  fun g {
    f();
  }
}
```

This seem a bit unwieldy, but it gets worse if `A` is defined in another file. Then I'd have to add a second `use A` (`require` won't do) outside of `B` like so:

```perl
use  A;
class B extends A {
  use A;
  fun g {
    f();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make lexical inclusion (of exported) functions work more elegantly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, thanks for using Moops! :-)

Second, it's probably a bad idea to name classes "B" in tests and examples. There's a module called [`B`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html) that comes with Perl, and Moops actually uses it!

Coming to your actual question, generally speaking with classes, you should be thinking `method` rather than `fun`. Method calls respect inheritance; function calls don't.

```
use Moops;

class AAA {
  method f {
    say "yay,f!";
  }
}

class BBB extends AAA {
  method g {
    $self->f;
  }
}

BBB->g;
```

Outputs:

```
yay,f!
```

If you want a library of convenience functions to be available in both `AAA` and `BBB` then, split those convenience functions into a separate package:

```
use Moops;

namespace MyUtils {
  use Exporter::Shiny qw( f );
  fun f {
    say "yay,f!";
  }
}

class AAA {
  use MyUtils -all;
  method m1 {
    f();
  }
}

class BBB extends AAA {
  use MyUtils -all;
  method m2 {
    f();
  }
}

BBB->m1;
BBB->m2;
```

Outputs:

```
yay,f!
yay,f!
```

You can even go a bit further and extend Moops from within. The following example defines a `:utils` trait that can be added to classes:

```
use Moops;

namespace MyUtils {
  use Exporter::Shiny qw( f );
  fun f {
    say "yay,f!";
  }
}

role Moops::TraitFor::Keyword::utils {
   around generate_package_setup {
     return (
       $self->$next(@_),
       'use MyUtils -all;',
     );
   }
}

class AAA :utils {
  method m1 {
    f();
  }
}

class BBB extends AAA :utils {
  method m2 {
    f();
  }
}

BBB->m1;
BBB->m2;
```

Same output as previous example.

Comment: Yeah, your right. Maybe my example was too simple to convey my intentions. I want the base class to supply "convenience functions" that don't access object state and I (am lazy and I) want to save some typing...

Comment: I've added a second example showing one way to supply convenience functions to both classes.